# Is there a way in Three JS to find the intersection lines between faces of 3d objects?

Tags: three.js

Suppose I have two objects that overlap, for example a cube and a cylinder like this:
[image]

I want to find the set of lines that define the intersection between the faces like this:
[image]

To be perfectly clear, hiding the 3d objects reveals just the lines I'm trying to compute:
[image]

Can I do this in Three JS? I made the pictures in Sketchup but am trying to do this programmatically in a web page.

Here's a view from the opposite corner in case it's hard to understand where the objects are relative to each other:
[image]